# javascriptのオブジェクトと配列について

Tags: javascript

javascriptのオブジェクトと配列について

下記のように作成するという事はわかったのですが、
純粋なオブジェクトと配列は、中カッコと大カッコの部分のみなのでしょうか？
つまり変数にオブジェクトと配列を代入していると考えてよいのでしょうか？

それともvar含むすべてがオブジェクトと配列そのものなのでしょうか？
変数名の部分が配列の名前とも聞きますが、初心者なので頭がこんがらがってしまいます

```
// 空の Object オブジェクトを作成する
var obj = { };

// 空の配列を作成する
var arr = [];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

javascriptでは[リテラル](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E3%83%AA%E3%83%86%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AB)形式でオブジェクト([オブジェクトリテラル](https://www.ajaxtower.jp/js/object/index2.html)、[オブジェクトリテラル表記法](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#%E3%82%AA%E3%83%96%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%83%86%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AB%E8%A1%A8%E8%A8%98%E6%B3%95_vs_JSON))を作成できるので「値を代入している？」と考えてらっしゃるかもしれません。

実際、略式で記載されているものをキチンと書くとこうなります。
[new演算子](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)を使用した初期化で作成されたものをインスタンスと呼びます。

```
var obj = new Object();
var arr = new Array();
```

また、別の言語では変数宣言型(Integer,String,Booleanなど)によって代入できる型に制限があったりしますが、
javascriptの変数宣言である`var`は代入される値によって任意の型に変わります。

```js
//number
var n = 1;
console.log((typeof n));

//string
n = "one : " + n;
console.log((typeof n));

//object(Array)
n = new Array();
console.log((typeof n));

//object
n = new Object();
console.log((typeof n));

//function
n = function(){ alert("Hello world"); };
console.log((typeof n));
```

上記を見て「ArrayもObjectって出てるじゃないか」と思うかもしれませんがjavascriptでのインスタンスは全てobject型となります。
javascriptにおけるArrayとは下記になります。

- 真偽判定で偽となる値ではない
- "object"型である
- "length"プロパティがある
- "length"プロパティが数値である
- "length"プロパティが列挙不可
- "splice"関数を保持

---

オブジェクト名の認識が下記のようなことであればその通りです。

```js
var obj = {};

//変数名として
obj["val1"] = "value one";

//オブジェクト名として
obj.val2 = "value two";

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
実際は
var obj = new Object();
var arr = new Array();
の省略だったのですね。それでは変数にオブジェクトと配列を代入しているのですね、そしてobjなどの変数名は結果的に代入するのでオブジェクト名と配列名にはなるが、あくまで本当は変数名という事でよいでしょうか？ただ代入されると結果として変数名イコールオブジェクト名になるので実質これがオブジェクト名になるという事でしょうか？

Comment: オブジェクト名の認識があっているか分かりませんが、概ねコメントの通りの認識でいいかと思います。試験コードを追記しましたので確認してみてください。

Comment: @nicomesecond  JavaScript に「オブジェクト名」「配列名」という物は無いと思います。オブジェクトが代入されている変数のことを「オブジェクト名」、配列が代入されている変数を「配列名」と言ったりすることは、文脈によってはあるかも知れませんね。

Comment: オブジェクト名、配列名という概念がjavascriptには存在しないのですね。

Comment: @nicomesecond 既にmjyさんにコメントいただいてますが何かと区別したいなど文脈にもよりますね。私は`obj.val1`を`オブジェクト名.プロパティ名`と呼び分けたりすることはあります。ただ、`obj`のみを指してオブジェクト名とは聞かないですね。どちらかというと単純に変数名といった呼び方をよく聞きます。

Comment: オブジェクト名、配列名という概念がjavascriptには存在しないので仕方がないので変数に代入して変数名でオブジェクト名配列名の代理をしているのですね。つまりどのオブジェクトか入れるかという区別を変数名で行わないといけないのですね。恐らくjsだけでしょうが。

Comment: すると純粋にオブジェクトそのものは{ };の部分だけで配列も[];のぶぶんのみなのですね。

Comment: もしかして、オブジェクト型、配列型のことでしょうか。

Comment: 私も初心者なのでよくわかっておらず恐縮ですがデータ型というよりそのものの部分がどれなのか知っておきたかったという事です。

Comment: @nicomesecond 実体を気にしていらっしゃるのでしょうか？`new`とは雛形(`Object()`)から実体(インスタンス)を作成する命令なので、`{}`や`[]`は雛形(実体の設計図)みたいなものです。実体は変数内に格納されています。恐らく一般に出回っている話より一歩踏み込んだことが知りたいのでしょうが、`new`などの話になると`JavaScript`での`Object`や`Array`の話から逸れ長くなってしまうので、一度、切って新しい質問をなさるといいかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。{}や[]はオブジェクト配列その物ではないですね。この設計によって作られた配列オブジェクトは変数の中にあるので、変数の中身を見ないと見る事ができないのでしょうね。